# Caching logged user panel in Symfony2

Tags: caching, symfony

I'm about to add caching to my website, but I'm a bit confused on how to cache/not cache information about logged user in header.
Imagine that some controller renders bundle:controller:view.twig template. And I cache this view inside controller for 1 week. 
I also include bundle:controller:part that displays some part which is cached for 1 month.
The problem is that view.twig extends some base.twig with header section that displays 'hello guest' or 'hello user@user.com' depending on authentication.

Should I include some mini controller (bundle:controller:login_info) that renders 'hello' information in base.twig? Or is there other, simpler method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several types of cache that you can use with Symfony2.

- With the built-in **reverse proxy** and support for **HTTP cache**, you can only cache entire webpages.
- If you want to cache page fragments, you will have to use **Edge Side Includes (ESI)**. It looks like it is what you are looking for if you want only the part "hello guest" not to be cached.

[The chapter about Caching from the Symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) is very well written and explains how to setup all kind of caches for your application (whole page or fragments).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I ahve already read Symfony book Caching chapter. Could you only answer two last questions: "Should I include some mini controller (bundle:controller:login_info) that renders 'hello' information in base.twig? Or is there other, simpler method?"?

Comment: This is a way of doing, but I don't know if it is "best practice" or not.